# Problem with using rclinicaltrials package

Tags: r

I wish to use a package called rclinicaltrials, on using `install.packages()`, I get the following message -

> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘rclinicaltrials’ is not available for this version of R

> A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
> see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

And after installing, on using `library()`, I get the message -

> Error in library(rclinicaltrials) :
> there is no package called ‘rclinicaltrials’

Is there any way of using this package in my version of R? I am using R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18). Or do I need to install an older version of R?

Thank you

Comment: I think the package is no longer maintained and has been removed from CRAN. Did you install it from the CRAN Archive?

Comment: Yes, looks like it is only availaible in the archive. I only used install.packages()

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to do?  Create TLFs?

Comment: I am trying to get data from the website in excel format in order to conduct some analysis.

Comment: Also still on github, but also no longer maintained there. https://github.com/sachsmc/rclinicaltrials

Comment: Looks like the AACT database site has capabilities to download the same information using RPostgreSQL: https://aact.ctti-clinicaltrials.org/r

Comment: Yes, I also discovered the same yesterday. I am trying to learn it